# Python dataframe, drop everything after a certain record

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], \
                   'counter' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], \
                   'status':['a', 'b', 'b' ,'c', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b'], \
                   'additional_data' : [12,35,13,523,6,12,6,1,46,236]}, \
                  columns=['id', 'counter', 'status', 'additional_data'])

df
Out[37]:  
    id  counter status  additional_data
0   1        1      a               12
1   1        2      b               35
2   1        3      b               13
3   1        4      c              523
4   2        1      a                6
5   2        2      a               12
6   2        3      a                6
7   3        1      a                1
8   3        2      a               46
9   3        3      b              236
```

The `id` column indicates which data belongs together, the `counter` indicates the order of the rows, and `status` is a special status code. I want to drop all rows after the first occurence of a row with `status='b'`, keeping the first row with `status='b'`.

Final output should look like this

```
   id  counter status  additional_data
0   1        1      a               12
1   1        2      b               35
4   2        1      a                6
5   2        2      a               12
6   2        3      a                6
7   3        1      a                1
8   3        2      a               46
9   3        3      b              236
```

All help is, as always, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom function with [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) for return index of values by condition, add `1` for not lost `b` row:

```
def f(x):
    m = x['status'].eq('b')
    b = m.idxmax()
    if m.any():
        x = x.loc[:b]
    else:
        x
    return x


a = df.groupby('id', group_keys=False).apply(f)
print (a)
   id  counter status  additional_data
0   1        1      a               12
1   1        2      b               35
4   2        1      a                6
5   2        2      a               12
6   2        3      a                6
7   3        1      a                1
8   3        2      a               46
9   3        3      b              236
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. Are you sure about this one? I'm not able to reproduce your answer :| when i run your function it returns the index values [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]

Comment: I use last version of pandas, what is problem? Some error?

Comment: im on pandas 20.3 as well. Did you see my edit of the comment regarding the output I get? I simply copy pasted your answer (and my own code into a fresh spyder window)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I could have spotted that `iloc` bug myself. But you know how it is when you are looking at somebody elses code :)

Comment: `df.groupby('id', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:x.status.eq('b').idxmax()+1])` may not need `f` perhaps?

Comment: Hi agian. I'm not sure this solution is 100% correct. I'm not sure where the error is. But it doesn't  seem to give correct output for cases where there is no `status='b'`. (drop id = 1 and 3 from the dataframe and see)

Comment: I try test, give me some time.

Comment: You are rigth, need `if-else`. Please check it now.

Comment: Super, nice day!